# how to show live direction of a source to destination using android

Tags: android, dictionary

In google map direction app user can see only source to destination live direction route map. Is it possible to show live direction of a source to destination using android ? I am new to android and i need some links to carry on. I have tried google map direction api but failed

Comment: If you need more help,i am available here. :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using Google Map (Direction) APi for android.
First follow these links:

[Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/)

[Direction APi](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro)

After that, when you will be able to get response from Google Direction Api for two points (Source and destination).
Here is a code snippet used to get Poly Lines:

```
public static ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {

    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    try {
        int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
        int lat = 0, lng = 0;

        while (index < len) {
            int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lat += dlat;

            shift = 0;
            result = 0;
            do {
                b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
                result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
                shift += 5;
            } while (b >= 0x20);
            int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
            lng += dlng;

            LatLng p = new LatLng((((double) lat / 1E5)), (((double) lng / 1E5)));
            poly.add(p);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Just toUser avoid crash
        LogUtils.LOGE("Exception", "In Valid POINTS", e);
    }

    return poly;
}
```